# CakePHP: How to access $this->request inside a model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm on CakePHP v2.4.

In a model's `afterSave()` callback, I want to do something conditionally, depending on conditions of the request. However `$this->request` does not seem to be defined here:

```
public function afterSave( $created, $options=array() ) {
    $this->log( $this->request ); //NOTHING HERE
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can access it via the global Router class.

```
public function afterSave( $created, $options=array() ) {
    $this->log( Router::getRequest() );
}
```

Comment: You just rocked my socks off!

Comment: Still works in Cake 3; found this to be the answer to helping me move some event listeners out of a controller and into a more central location. Finding the relevant query string info ahead of time and passing it all the way through was not a good solution due to the levels of abstraction involved; the controller had no way to know what events might be fired or what the event listener might need to know.

Comment: how to get request parameter form `data` section and link to documentation

Answer (score 7):

Instead of calling a single tone (Router::getRequest()) in the afterSave() method and introducing tight coupling like suggested by Mathew, why cant you pass whatever parameter you need there along with the data of the record you try to save?

It will be present in $this->data in the afterSave() then. Plus this way it is easy to test. Have fun testing Router::getRequest() in this method.

If you need the whole request there you can add a property Model::$request to AppModel and a method setRequest() there as well and in your controllers beforeFilter() you can do $this->{$this->modelClass}->setRequest($this->request);

Comment: +1 good advise. Looks like he's trying to log something. I'd recommend moving that logging code out of the model to the Lib folder, then when the logger object is created pass in the request data and then attach that logger to your model. The model shouldn't care that the logger needs to know about the current request.

Comment: "Have fun testing Router::getRequest() in this method."  I had fun trying to test it. It's much easier to get the request->data set in test using `$this->Model->request = new CakeRequest(); $this->Model->request->data = $this->testData;`